# How to show in a list only upcoming events in a calendar overlay using office 365.

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365

I have a calendar overlay in office 365 site, 8-9 category in this calendar.
I want show a different list bottom of this calendar page, all upcoming events in list view type.

Embody have idea how to achieve this please share.
Please check Screenshot.
[image]
Thanks for advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sort section choose start time column and set ">= Today" and then you'll get only upcoming events